# Old Ladies Day Out

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image: header]

During this unfortunate Corona situation in Stackville the WalMart is closed every Monday, BestBUY is closed every Tuesday, the Liquor Store  is closed every Thursday, and the bank is open only on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday.

Everything of course is closed on Sunday.

One afternoon Mrs. Fernald, Mrs. Wakefield, Mrs. Greenwood, and Mrs. Charles went shopping together, each with a different place to go. On their way they dropped the following remarks:

[image: ladies]

**Mrs. Fernald:** Mrs. Charles and I wanted to go earlier in the week but there wasn't a day when we could both take care of our errands.

**Mrs. Wakefield:** I didn't want to come today but tomorrow I couldn't do what I have to do.

**Mrs. Greenwood:** I could have gone yesterday or the day before just as well as today.

**Mrs. Charles:** Either yesterday or tomorrow would have suited me.

---

#### Which place did each old lady need to visit in town?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        |Mon |Tue |Wed |Thur|Fri |Sat |Sun
WalMart |    |o   |o   |o   |o   |o   |
BestBUY |o   |    |o   |o   |o   |o   |
Liquor  |o   |o   |o   |    |o   |o   |
Bank    |o   |    |o   |    |o   |    |
```

First,

> today is Wednesday or Friday as those two days are the only days which all mentioned place opens.

If

> today is Wednesday, Mrs. Charles is going to WalMart, Mrs. Greenwood is going to Liquor Store, Mrs. Wakefield is going to the Bank and Mrs. Fernald is going to BestBUY. This can be verified that all statements are true in this case.

If

> today is Friday. But Mrs. Fernald and Mrs. Charles can take care both of their errands on Wednesday, wherever they go.

So

> today is Wednesday, Mrs. Fernald is going to BestBUY, Mrs. Wakefield is going to the bank, Mrs. Greenwood is going to Liquor Store and Mrs. Charles is going to WalMart.

Comment: I don't think that chart ***is*** a spoiler. It's not the solution; it's just a nice formulation of the first bit of information given in the OP. No need to spoilertag it IMO.